# TFS/MSBuild Generic test - how to specify project-relative path

Tags: tfs, msbuild, environment-variables

I'm trying to get Silverlight unit tests integrated into a TFS build using a "[Generic Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182624%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" on a test project to wrap [Statlight](http://statlight.codeplex.com/)

When I hard code the paths to everything it works fine but I'm tearing my hair out trying to work out how to pass project-relative paths to the generic test so that it works in the TFS build environment.

The closest I've come is to have the build process workflow set environment variables pointing to StatLight and the xap files containing the SL unit tests so that I can reference those in the command line arguments to statlight.

Feels hacky though - is there a better way of getting path information into generic tests based on the current solution/build configuration?

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182626%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#RunGenericTest) uses a couple of environment variables (**%TestDeploymentDir%** for one) that I can't find documented anywhere so I'm wondering if there are any more magic variables that I can use to infer paths from rather than having to set my own.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some references on MSBuild properties:

- [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)
- [MSBuild Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)
- [Team Build 2008 Property Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/02/12/team-build-2008-property-reference.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for the useful references, thanks. Not quite what I was looking for though - essentially I want to avoid setting environment variables by using some of those properties directly but it looks like the generic test framework isn't set up that way.